# is mail() function of PHP encrypted already?

Tags: php, email

Please anybody tell me is mail() function of PHP is already encrypted or i have to make it encrypted my self, i want to make secure travel of email.

Comment: Secure travel? Use `https` that'll secure your form until the postman gets back from the bar; that's **if** he makes it there, and/or comes back in one piece.

Comment: Email is never secure.

Comment: That entirely depends on your SMTP server.

Comment: `mail` is about the lowest level API there is. No, it doesn't do anything like encryption. What kind of encryption are you talking about?

Comment: @Fred-ii- ? I think you mean SSL.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Yah... that's the ticket ;-)

Answer (score 3):

to use SSL or TLS with `mail()`, you will have to configure the "php.ini" (Require SSL on your server):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/mail.configuration.php

```
SMTP = YOUR_SERVER
smtp_port = SMTP_SECURE_PORT
sendmail_from = SEND_MAIL_FROM
sendmail_path = SEND_MAIL_APP
```

But if you change your server, you have to do it again, so I recommend instead of using `mail()` use SMTP, there are ready-made classes, see:

PHPMailer download: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

Example PHPMailer with TLS:

```
<?php
require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'smtp1.example.com;smtp2.example.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'user@example.com';                 // SMTP username
$mail->Password = 'secret';                           // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable encryption, 'ssl' also accepted

$mail->From = 'from@example.com';
$mail->FromName = 'Mailer';
$mail->addAddress('joe@example.net', 'Joe User');     // Add a recipient
$mail->addAddress('ellen@example.com');               // Name is optional
$mail->addReplyTo('info@example.com', 'Information');
$mail->addCC('cc@example.com');
$mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');

$mail->WordWrap = 50;                                 // Set word wrap to 50 characters
$mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');         // Add attachments
$mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');    // Optional name
$mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
$mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'Message has been sent';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `mail()` function will either use the local mailer (Linux) or will connect to standard port 25 (Windows). There's absolutely no way to:

- Make it use <del>another port</del> an encrypted channel
- Provide authentication data

If security (or reliability) is a concern, avoid it at all cost.